# Visual Studio - How to create a solution from existing solutions/projects including webservices and a web that uses those webservices?

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How do I create the solution in Visual Studio 2008 from which I should be able to press F5 (debug) and get all webservices going aswell as start up Microsoft Internet Explorer with the frontpage of the websolution?

I need to create a solution in which I will add all existing projects for an existing application. The projects are at present located in several diffrent solutions, several for diffrent webservices and one for the main web application, which makes it hard to debug. I have tried to just create a new solution and add all existing projects, but it did not work - the webservices won't start automatically. If there is some configuration that needs to be done in order to get the webservices started, please explain that part too.

Sorry for not being able to include any example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add nothing but existing projects to a solution then you should use the Blank Solution template.  You can then use the Add Existing Project option to add the projects to the solution.

As for running multiple projects when debugging, right-click the solution and select Set Startup Projects.  You can then select multiple startup projects instead of just one.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this (used the template Empty Website - might be the problem).

Comment: Was not able to compile this time: File --> New --> Project From Existing Code - didnt work. I didnt get the possibility to choose WebApplication, only ConsoleApplication, WindowsApplication and ClassLibrary. Went with WindowsApplication which doesnt build.

Comment: I wasn't referring to that menu item.  Right-click the solution in the Solution Explorer and then select the item I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, that was how I did it, thou not rightclicking on the Solution --> Add --> Existing Project, but using File --> Add --> Existing Project, which is the same menu in two diffrent places, last week. Got it to compile, but not to start the webservices. Many thanks for your answer, it will possibly help others with similar problem. I will continue to look for some sort of configuration that starts up the webservices within the solution.

Comment: Thanks again. After getting the individual projects to start (needed to recompile twice due to dependencies that was not clear from the start) I was able to get it all working thanks to your second answer (Set Startup Projects). Choosing the Multiple Startup alternative was the solution.